# I need to code a 1 22 333 4444 pattern in python with while loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have to do the pattern 
1
22
333
4444
with while loops in python

```
def EXwhile6 ():
    '''This funtion prints a pattern. The user enters how many lines'''
    #Init
    a = input ("Write how many lines you want to print: ")
    a = int(a)
    K = 1
    #Condition
    while K <= a: 
        #Action
        line = str(K)
        #Update
        line2 = line + str(K)
        print (line2)
        K += 1
EXwhile6 ()
```

The output should be

```
1
22
333
4444
```

I tried that code and I obtain

```
11
22
33
44
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the idiomatic way to do it in Python, using the fact that a string can be "multiplied":

```
def EXwhile6 ():
    a = input("Write how many lines you want to print: ")
    a = int(a)
    K = 1
    while K <= a:
        print(str(K) * K)
        K += 1
```

Now, if you want to code it by hand you'd need a nested loop; the above is equivalent to:

```
def EXwhile6 ():
    a = input("Write how many lines you want to print: ")
    a = int(a)
    K = 1
    while K <= a:
        J = 1
        while J <= K:
            print(K, end="")
            J += 1
        print()
        K += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You've left out a processing step.  Your loop body

```
    line = str(K)
    line2 = line + str(K)
    print (line2)
```

... specifically concatenates exactly *two* copies of the number, and print that out.

Instead of two copies, you need a loop that will concatenate `K` copies, rather than two.

Since your posted code shows that you already know how to write a loop to execute `K` times, I expect that you can fix it from here.

Answer (score 0):

You keep adding the same number (`K`) to your line. You need a second loop to count from `1` to `K`. Modify the `while` loop as follows:

```
while K <= a:
    #Action
    line = ""
    #Update
    for j in range(1, K + 1):
        line = line + str(K)
    print (line)
    K += 1
```

As a side note, the whole program can be written in a single line using list comprehensions and `.join()`:

```
def EXwhile6 ():
    a = input ("Write how many lines you want to print: ")
    print "\n".join([str(x) * x for x in range(1, int(a) + 1)])
EXwhile6()
```